# No react output from my webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

What's wrong with my configuration , It serves the index.html with no react output.Been tooling with this for weeks , is there a simpler way to do this?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry:[
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
'webpack/hot/dev-server',
 './src/index.js'
 ],
 output: {
 filename: 'bundle.js',
 path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

 },
 module: {
 loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query:
    {
        presets:['es2015', 'react']
    }
  }]
 },
resolve:{
extensions :['.js','.jsx']
},plugins: [
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],
devServer: {
contentBase:'./dist/',
compress: true,
hotOnly: true

}
```

};

Comment: Did you have a look -> https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/380 ... It seems like others were having the exact issues. And seems like problem is that react is in node_modules folder that is excluded in loaders. Try removing the line, and see if it works.